# What native javascript method is capable of creating a server?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to nodejs. I have successfully installed it on my computer (and rebooted). I have created a hello_world.js inside `My Documents` directory (I'm on a windows xp computer):

```
console.log("hello world");
var my_http   = require( 'http' );
var my_server = my_http.createServer( ... ) ;
...
```

I have successfully opened a windows command prompt, cd'd to the `My Documents` directory, executed the .js file, and received 'hello world' output. And I have navigated my browser to the running localhost port (for my experiment: `http://localhost:1337/`)

But I have 2 major questions based on this:

**1** - where is 'http' ... I suppose it is a module(?), but I do not find such a directory within my nodejs installation directory.

**2** - how does the `http` method, `createServer`, actually create a server? Does native javascript have such a method?

Comment: [http](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) is a native node API. It's not built into the language, it's built into the runtime.

Comment: so does that mean that 'http' is located within the 'node.exe' file? ...

Comment: No, `http` and `creatServer` are not part of javascript, they're part of node. Just like `window` and `document` aren't part of javascript, they're part of the DOM api exposed by the browser.

Comment: ... but I understand that nodejs is js ... isn't nodejs written in javascript?

Comment: @dsdsdsdsd: Yes, exactly. In fact, you can open the `node.exe` file in an editor and you will find [the source of the `http` module](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/http.js) buried in there, accessing node's raw HTTP api (that is written in C++).

Comment: bergi ... thanks ... still confused though ... the github link you provided shows http.js ... but you suggested that http is C++ (as @KevinB also implied I believe) .. thanks again ...

Comment: No, they implied it wasn't part of JavaScript (a language) but part of Node (a JS ecosystem).

Comment: @dsdsdsdsd: `http.js` is a layer around the c++ stuff (`process.binding('http_parser')`) and is available as a builtin library.

Comment: hello ... slight variation on my primary question please: I am a webpage guy ... I make websites ... ... ...  do I need to worry about `require( 'http' );` and `.createServer( ... )` when I am building a website ?? ... ... ... I think I am beginning to understand that that is Server Administrator stuff (kind of the way the Apache config files work )... am I on the right track ??? ... thanks

Answer (score 2):

The node.js standard library is written in Javascript and C++, and C++ modules can be loaded in js code via `process.binding`. Specifically for `http.createServer`, it's a wrapper around [`_http_server.Server`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_http_server.js#L222), which invokes [`net.Server`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/net.js#L1073), which uses the C++ [TCP wrapper](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/src/tcp_wrap.cc) .

See [here](http://darksi.de/c.cpp-in-node/) for more details.

To answer the second question, `createServer` just creates and populates the control object, the actual work is in [`listen`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/net.js#L1190), which first [creates a handle](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/net.js#L1131) and this is where C++ code is actually [called](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/net.js#L1159) for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

1) http is a built-in node module. You can read up on the documentation for it here: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html. Node provides a lot of modules out of the box to assist w/ everyday operations (interacting w/ file systems, making HTTP requests, creating servers, working with paths, etc.)

2) Not sure what you mean by "native" JavaScript. JavaScript is just a language. I think you're really asking about the runtime environment. If you are using JavaScript in the browser, then no you can't start an HTTP server. But Node.js runs on the server, so in this environment it can do all sorts of stuff that you can't do w/ JavaScript in the browser, such as access the file system.

Comment: "node.js runs on the server" ... I thought nodejs was the server ... if not, on what server does it run .... thanks

Comment: @dsdsdsdsd: "server" here refers to the machine (computer) that runs the server application… uh…